# Huawei APK Uploading Error: Calculated Signature does not match

Tags: bash, apk, sha256, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to upload apk/aab file to Huawei App Gallery via APIs. I successfully get upload URL and necessary parameters to upload a file. On upload file step I get this error. I used bash.

Error message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Based on this document page about [Obtaining the File Upload URL](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-upload-url-new-0000001111685200#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001111685200__en-us_topic_0000001057512485_p173701128151713), I have assigned sha parameter to variable like this. I removed ":" between characters.

`sha256="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"`

with this **sha256** and other parameters, I get upload url successfully. I store response body to a json file, and parse needed parts for [upload file](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-upload-file-new-0000001111845090) request.

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "client_id: $clientid"  -X GET 'https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/publish/v2/upload-url/for-obs?...' | jq  . > old.json


url=$(cat old.json | jq -r .urlInfo.url)


authorization=$(cat old.json | jq   -r .urlInfo.headers.Authorization)

amzcontent256=$(cat old.json | jq  -r '.urlInfo.headers."x-amz-content-sha256"')

amz256date=$(cat old.json | jq   -r '.urlInfo.headers."x-amz-date"')

hosttype=$(cat old.json | jq  -r .urlInfo.headers.Host)

useragent=$(cat old.json | jq  -r '.urlInfo.headers."user-agent"')

contentyp=$(cat old.json | jq  -r '.urlInfo.headers."Content-Type"')
```

I use this parameters in upload request.

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' -H "x-amz-content-sha256:$amzcontent256" -H "x-amz-date:$amz256date" -H "Host:$hosttype"  -H "user-agent:$useragent" -H "Authorization:$authorization" -F 'file=@/Users/app1/apkfolder/test.apk' -X  PUT $uploadurl`

Response says

> <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I am positive that my sha variable and sha256 fingerprint on app gallery on targeted app is same.

I think I assign sha key wrong but I don't know what to do at this point.